# create-react-app typescript won't run npm start

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-tsx, react-typescript

I am trying to `create-react-app` with typescript, but there seems to be a problem with JSX and TS. I read a couple of possible solutions, that didn't work out for me.

I have:

- npm: version 16.14.7
- node: version 14.8.0

I used `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` from the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation)

The installation went fine, but when I try to run `npm start` it gives me this error:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /Users/.../react-types/my-app
> react-scripts start

/Users/.../react-types/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239
      appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'jsx' of object '#<Object>'
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (/Users/.../react-types/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../react-types/my-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to change this line 238 in `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js` as [suggested by tudor07 here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9868#issuecomment-723576740):

```
} else if (parsedCompilerOptions[option] !== valueToCheck) {
```

to

```
} else if (parsedCompilerOptions[option] !== valueToCheck && option !== "jsx") {
```

and that let me run `npm start` and the server is up and running. But it now reveals that it won't recognize JSX/TSX:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/.../react-types/my-app/src/App.tsx(7,5):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react/jsx-runtime'. '/Users/.../react-types/my-app/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'react' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react`  TS7016

     5 | function App() {
     6 |   return (
  >  7 |     <div className="App">
       |     ^
     8 |       <header className="App-header">
     9 |         <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    10 |         <p>
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION (for me at least)**

In my `tsconfig.json` I changed the my `"compilerOptions":` from `"jsx": "react-jsx"` to `"jsx": "react"`. Notice that I still needed to make a change on line 238 in my `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js` as [suggested by tudor07 here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9868#issuecomment-723576740)

Please let me know if it's too "hacky"

Comment: I have noticed, that you have react:17 but types is for react 16. Please update your @types/react to v.17.*.
Also move your @types/** to devDependencies

Comment: [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) says latest version is 16.9.56? @captain-yossarian

Comment: Here is the link to source code: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/3a98ed1c2457f6f507652f7dfd52de00b0e3d6d7/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js#L247

Please find verifyTypeScriptSetup in your node_modules (node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239)  and add there console.logs. It will be easier for you to debug

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you, but sorry - I don't really get what I'm supposed to do. have you read my update in the question? I think the real error is revealed there

Answer (score 2):

In my case @captain-yossarian had it right. Out of date types (`@types/react@16.9.4`) given the specified version of React (`react@17.0.1`). To fix:

```
npm install --upgrade @types/react@17
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I deleted the tsconfig.json file then run yarn start, and it worked

Maybe a problem with create-react-app, I uninstalled it then reinstalled